# Hide data attribute with css3

Tags: jquery, css

Working on my website, I'm adding some functions like the one provided with [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js) (adds a lateral menu, like facebook one).

My problem comes when working with responsive styles.

I can hide the dragg option with the following value: `<data-snap-ignore="true">`. But I don't know how to hide it with `display:none` on desktop resolutions (to avoid issues with the mouse), and allow it back on low resolutions (like tablets and mobile).

Is there any clue about how to hide it with CSS3?

Comment: Have you looked at media queries?

Comment: I am working with media queries, but can't figure out how to hide only the data atribute

Comment: @XaviAlsina can you share an example code in jsfiddle or any other

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries for Standard Devices

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```